# Slicebox 3D Compatibility

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, animation

I've recently had the necessity to use Slicebox 3D animation to animate pictures on a website.
While firefox and chrome render the animation just fine, the author planned a fade back on IE because of the fact that it wouldn't support these animation.
IE now supports them tho, but not in the correct way. If you open this [website](http://tympanus.net/Development/Slicebox/) through IE the animation will appear corrupted. Any idea what workaround would work inside the slicebox.js in order to force the fade In Out?

What I got by now is it :

```
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6

            if (isIE === false){
            $('#sb-slider').slicebox(options);
            }else{
            $('#sb-slider').slicebox(options, isIE);
            };
```

the isIE variable gets used in the js file to forse this.support to false in case IE is detected.

What isn't workign right now is that IE falls back on the fade, but renderes the images way too big for a little while before changing them to the correct size.
Any ideas?

Comment: 2 years later I have the same problem. Any luck with finding a solution?